# Removed Word COM Add-in always comes back

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I wanted to either disable or remove a COM add-in from my Word application. I went into options -> Add-ins -> selected Manage Com Add-ins -> Clicked on Go.
I see a list of add-ins there, there's one particular add-in that I'm trying to either disable or remove. In this case the add-in is "SAP Business One".
I tried disabling it and removing it. But after I close Word and open it again, the add-in is still there and enabled and runnnig.
Is there a more forceful way to do this?

Comment: Some things to try: 
- start MS Word as administrator and try to remove the add-in
- Manually delete the folders for the add-in under the `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins` regkey

Comment: Thank you. I think the regkey you mentioned is what I'm looking for. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to directly delete the registry key for the add-on, it should be a child key under `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins`.